# Can this tire be repaired or should I replace it?

Tags: sidewall-damage, tires

I hit a curb, I was going with not more than 2-5 mph. Can I fix this tire or it has to be replaced? [image]

Comment: Cannot see how deep it goes in your pic, if you cannot see any sidewall cords down in there then you are probably good.